# How to convert array of String in hex to array of int using Java?

Tags: java, hex

I have a class like below

```
public class EXOR{

    public static void conv(){
        String [] Parray={"243f6a88","85a308d3","13198a2e","03707344","a4093822","299f31d0","082efa98",
                "ec4e6c89","452821e6", "38d01377", "be5466cf","34e90c6c","c0ac29b7","c97c50dd","3f84d5b5","b5470917","9216d5d9","8979fb1b"};

        String binAddr[]=new String[18];
        for (int i=0;i<18;i++)
        {
            int x[]=new int[18];
            binAddr[i]= Integer.toBinaryString(Integer.parseInt(Parray[i],16));
            System.out.println("binernya : " +binAddr[i]);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new EXOR().conv();

    }
}
```

and I want to convert that array to binary array format. 
I want to get output like below
for example

```
00100100001111110110101010001000
10000111101000110000100011010011
................................
```

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Java is not a scripting language; this is not a script; and an array of Strings containing hex is not an int array of hex.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose while executing your code you must've got a number point exception. This occurs when the Hexadecimal string is out of the range of Integer.

You can use:

```
    binAddr[i]= (new BigInteger(Parray[i],16)).toString(2);
```

instead of

`binAddr[i]= Integer.toBinaryString(Integer.parseInt(Parray[i],16));`

This will solve your problem for quick reference
[Big Integer Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

Answer (score 0):

**Code:**

```
public class EXOR {

    public static void conv(){

        String [] Parray={"243f6a88","85a308d3","13198a2e","03707344","a4093822","299f31d0","082efa98",
                "ec4e6c89","452821e6", "38d01377", "be5466cf","34e90c6c","c0ac29b7","c97c50dd","3f84d5b5","b5470917","9216d5d9","8979fb1b"};

        String [] binAddr = new String[Parray.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < binAddr.length; i++)
        {
            int strLen = Parray[i].length();
            binAddr[i] = "";

            for(int j = 0; j < strLen; j++) {
                String temp = Integer.toBinaryString(
                        Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(
                                Parray[i].charAt(j)), 16));

                // Pad with leading zeroes
                for(int k = 0; k < (4 - temp.length()); k++) {
                    binAddr[i] += "0";
                }
                binAddr[i] += temp;
            }

            System.out.println("Original: " + Parray[i]);
            System.out.println("Binary: " + binAddr[i]);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        conv();
    }
}
```

**First few lines of Output:**

```
Original: 243f6a88
Binary: 00100100001111110110101010001000
Original: 85a308d3
Binary: 10000101101000110000100011010011
```

Answer (score 0):

We have Integer.MAX_VALUE = 2147483647
But, the 2nd item "85A308D3" = 2242054355. It exceed the capability of an Integer.

So, you use `Integer.parseInt(85A308D3)` will cause `java.lang.NumberFormatException`.

To fix it, change your code to use `Long` instead of `Integer`

```
        binAddr[i] = Long.toBinaryString(Long.parseLong(Parray[i], 16));
```

Hope this help!